# Rails 5.2 Cache Store with Redis not allowing user to login in development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I am running a rails 5.2 application in docker, everything was working well with session storage until today, I tried to change the `session_store` from `cookie_store` to `cache_store`, using Redis.

In my config/initializers/session_store.rb file I have this, this is the only option that works in development (take note of the `cookie_store`):

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                           key: "_app_#{Rails.env}_session",
                                           domain: %w[.example.ru .example.io],
                                           expire_after: 24.hours,
                                           httponly: false
```

The config with the `cache_store` doesn't work in development env but works in production.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cache_store,
                                       key: "_app_#{Rails.env}_session",
                                       domain: %w[.example.ru .example.io],
                                       expire_after: 24.hours,
                                       httponly: false
```

In the my env files i have this:
`config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }`

In the `.env` file my redis url is `REDIS_URL=redis://0.0.0.0:6379/0`

And there's no error log in the console. Any idea why cache_store isn't working in development env?

And by the way, I'm using Devise gem for authentication.

### Update with server logs

#### Log when using `cookie_store`

```
web_1        | Started POST "/api/v1/auth" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-10-10 15:21:12 +0000
web_1        | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1        |    (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
web_1        |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
web_1        | Processing by API::V1::AuthenticationController#create as HTML
web_1        |   Parameters: {"email"=>"user1@yandex.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "authentication"=>{"email"=>"user1@yandex.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
web_1        |   User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "user1@yandex.ru"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:15
web_1        |    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:19
web_1        |   User Update (1.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", "2018-10-10 15:21:14.709422"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2018-10-10 14:05:32.458533"], ["sign_in_count", 15], ["updated_at", "2018-10-10 15:21:14.716641"], ["id", 106]]
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:19
web_1        |    (1.5ms)  COMMIT
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:19
web_1        | [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.15ms)
web_1        | Completed 200 OK in 615ms (Views: 165.5ms | ActiveRecord: 16.7ms)
web_1        | 
web_1        | 
web_1        | Started GET "/dashboard" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-10-10 15:21:14 +0000
web_1        | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1        | Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
```

#### Log when using `cache_store` (this doesn't redirect to the dashboard, it stays on the same page and simply rerenders the login page).

```
web_1        | Started POST "/api/v1/auth" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-10-10 15:29:43 +0000
web_1        | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1        | Processing by API::V1::AuthenticationController#create as HTML
web_1        |   Parameters: {"email"=>"user1@yandex.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "authentication"=>{"email"=>"user1@yandex.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
web_1        |   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "user1@yandex.ru"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:15
web_1        |    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:19
web_1        |   User Update (3.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", "2018-10-10 15:29:44.123755"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2018-10-10 15:21:14.709422"], ["sign_in_count", 16], ["updated_at", "2018-10-10 15:29:44.132142"], ["id", 106]]
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:19
web_1        |    (1.6ms)  COMMIT
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/authentication_controller.rb:19
web_1        | [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.17ms)
web_1        | Completed 200 OK in 489ms (Views: 199.9ms | ActiveRecord: 16.1ms)
web_1        | 
web_1        | 
web_1        | Started GET "/dashboard" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-10-10 15:29:44 +0000
web_1        | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1        | Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
web_1        | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
web_1        | Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
web_1        | Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
web_1        | 
web_1        | 
web_1        | Started GET "/login" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-10-10 15:29:44 +0000
web_1        | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1        | Processing by HomeController#login as HTML
web_1        |   Rendering home/login.html.haml within layouts/application
web_1        |   Rendered home/login.html.haml within layouts/application (5.0ms)
web_1        | Completed 200 OK in 760ms (Views: 739.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

From updating the logs, I noticed the difference, the `cache_store` log has this error - `Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected` This must be the proble.
Currently researching on the possible ways to fix that.

Comment: post a minimal public repo on Github demo-ing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BKSpurgeon the main problem is that the app just doesn't leave the login page even after the user has been authenticated, as confirmed through the rails logs. I'm going to update the question with logs when using `cookie_store` and when using `cache_store` maybe that could further help us understand the problem.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon updated the question with the logs, please take a look.

Comment: is it solved/fixed?

Comment: No it’s not solved or fixed. Needed the redis-server credentials to be supplied as JSON so I ended up using the redis-rails gem so that I could serialize the redis server credentials, but still redis doesn’t work for cache in development. I’m currently trying to use my redis server credentials from Heroku in dev env, but still can’t get it to work. My current temporary fix is to use cookie_store in dev env and redis store in production. Have you found a solution?

Comment: no i barely understand the problem! a minimal solution would make it easier to solve for SO users though

Comment: @BKSpurgeon thank you very much for your interest in helping to solve this problem, it's easy to recreate this problem, just create a new rails app and then try to store the cookie in the cache_store, it doesn't work (I realize that cache_store is only meant to store caches and not session cookies I suppose? If so be it, why would they create a solution for caches but not a matching solution for cookies? How can I store cookies on redis in the development environment?).

Comment: All I just wanted was a way to store my cookie in redis and then be able to retrieve in another app running on a Golang backend within the subdomain of my root domain (the main app running in rails).